# ViewModel callback for Close(this) call

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

ViewModel ***A*** calls ShowViewModel to ViewModel ***B***. If B calls Close(this), it closes and go back to ***A***.

Is there a way for ViewModel ***A*** know that ***B*** was closed? Something like a CallBack?

Thanks!

Comment: Do any of these help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319529/returning-values-to-parent-viewmodel-in-mvvmcross, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952101/how-make-a-viewmodel-return-data-to-another and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405470/how-do-i-update-the-parent-viewmodel-when-child-viewmodel-is-updated ? One "gotcha" to watch out for is that on some platforms (e.g. Droid) it's not always the case that the instance of ViewModel A will still be in memory when ViewModel B is closed - the operating system may "tombstone" and reinflate the A Activity/View while B is shown.

Comment: After watching N=12 video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QCIoIw_O4I#t=2797), I tried to use the message system to comunicate ViewModel A about the ViewModel B closing and it worked. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stuart mentioned in one of the comments, on Android there is no guarantee that activity A will still be running to receive a notification via messenger. My favorite approach to solving "notification"-like problems in MvvmCross is to design activity A and activity B to use shared data access layer and communicate via persisted state. When you start analyzing your application, you may discover that activity A may not need to know that activity B completed. Instead, it can respond to the changes in the underlying data.

Comment: In my case I need to refresh an entity list in ModelView A, since B contains a form the inserts a new tuple in the database. So how can I do that using your approach? Thanks!

Comment: Check http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/11/n42-is-my-viewmodel-visible-can-i-kill.html. You can use similar approach to re-load your data from the data layer when activity A is brought to the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best methods solving viewmodel interdependencies is using a loosely coupled approch using the MessageBus/Event Aggregator pattern. Many of the popular MVVM frameworks (ReactiveUI for example) ship with an implementation for this.

Comment: MvvmCross doesn't contain a built-in Messenger. A WeakReference-based one is provided via a plugin (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#messenger) but you are also free to use alternatives (e.g. TinyMessenger)